# Android GCM- Different register id for different apps?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use google cloud messaging  service. I want to use it with a few different applications. I need to get a registration ID, but will i have to get a different registration ID for each of my different applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GCM every application is one of the project. So on same device with different application you will get the different registration ID. for more info go to http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html